# table view no data showing in the table cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have face problem in that code when i have run that code then no data show in tableview on  it's table cell. there is no error in console but data not show. please Guide me what's the mistake i have do that code.

**InvoiceCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InvoiceCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ItemImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ItemName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ItemType;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *date;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Amount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;

@end
```

**InvoiceCell.m**

```
#import "InvoiceCell.h"

@implementation InvoiceCell
@synthesize ItemImage,ItemName,ItemType,Amount,status;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

**InvoiceViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InvoiceViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *DataImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *DataName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Datatype;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *DataAmount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *DataStatus;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Datadate;


@end
```

**InvoiceViewController.m**

```
#import "InvoiceViewController.h"
#import "InvoiceCell.h"

@interface InvoiceViewController ()

@end

@implementation InvoiceViewController
@synthesize DataImages,DataName,Datatype,DataAmount,DataStatus,Datadate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    DataImages = @[@"img1.jpg", @"img2.jpg", @"img3.jpg", @"img4.jpg", @"img5.jpg"];
    DataName = @[@"Suit", @"Shirt", @"paint", @"Suit", @"Suit"];
    Datatype = @[@"Brown", @"Black", @"Blue", @"Black", @"Blue"];
    DataAmount = @[@"$500", @"$400",@"$500", @"$400",@"$300"];
    DataStatus = @[@"Paid", @"Due", @"Paid", @"Due", @"Paid"];
    Datadate = @[@"8/5/2014", @"10/6/2014",@"8/5/2014", @"10/6/2014",@"8/5/2014"];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   // Return the number of sections.
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return DataName.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InvoiceCell";
    InvoiceCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[InvoiceCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    long row = [indexPath row];

    NSLog(@"%@", cell.ItemName.text = DataName[row]);
    cell.ItemName.text = DataName[row];
    cell.ItemType.text = Datatype[row];
    cell.ItemImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:DataImages[row]];
    cell.date.text = Datadate[row];
    cell.Amount.text = DataAmount[row];
    cell.status.text = DataStatus[row];

    return cell;

}
```

[image] [image]

In the Debug Window and console Data show but not show data on simulator screen in the tableview cells

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest starting to debug by putting NSLog() messages inside your controller methods to verify that they're being called and that they're getting/returning values that you expect.

Comment: I have used that NSLog(@"%@", cell.ItemName.text = DataName[row]); then I have see data is print on console successfully. but data is not  show on simulator screen, please help me.

Comment: Your IBOutlets should be @property (weak, nonatomic) ...

Comment: I have use that @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ItemName; but there is no data show on simulator table view

Comment: Where is the tableView in your code? I cant see a UITableView property in your InvoiceViewController...

Comment: Can you Guide me which UITableView property you have to talk.Please explain in detail.

Comment: I assume you have a .xib or a storyboard which contains a TableView, correct?

Comment: Are you sure your properties in InvoiceCell.h are hooked up to your InvoiceCell.xib label outlets?

Comment: @PortlandRunner I use Storyboard, I hooked my label outlets properties with InvoiceCell.h but data not show in table view cell, problem not solve yet now.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a tableView in your StoryBoard, but you have no connection to it in your code. Add this to your InvoiceViewController.h

```
@property IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

and hook it up to your TableView in Interface Builder.

Then you can set the DataSource and Delegate in your InvoiceViewController.m -[viewDidLoad] method

```
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Now the TableView will know to call the delegate methods you implemented and you should see your data in the table.

Comment: I have use this one but data not show in simulator table view cells

Comment: Put a NSLog statement or breakpoint inside the `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method and see if it is getting called.